# AngularJs active navigation item Issue

Tags: angularjs

I have in view :

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-controller="MenuItemCtrl as vm">
         <li ng-repeat="item in names" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-click="select($index)" ng-class="{active: $index == selected}"> 
             <a ng-show="{{item.up===true}}" href="#{{item.link}}">{{item.name}}</a>  
         </li>
    </ul>
```

and controller like this:

```
$scope.names = [{
                name: "Main",
                slug: "main",
                active: true,
                up:true,
                inFooter:false,
                link: "/"
            }, {
                name: "Pets",
                slug: "pets",
                active: false,
                up:true,
                link: "/pets"
            }, {
                name: "LDAdoption",
                slug: "ldAdoption",
                active: false,
                inFooter:false,
                up:true,
                link: "/ldAdoption"
            },{
                name: "Impressum",
                slug: "impressum",
                active: false,
                up:false,
                inFooter:true,
                link: "/impressum"
            }, {
                name: "Be a volunteer",
                slug: "volunteer",
                active: false,
                inFooter:true,
                up:false,
                link: "/volunteer"
            }, {
                name: "Contact",
                slug: "contact",
                active: false,
                up:true,
                inFooter:true,
                link: "/contact"
            }];
            $scope.selected = 0; 
         $scope.select= function(item) {
           $scope.selected = item; 
    };

        $scope.isActive = function(item) {
                return $scope.selected === item;
            };
```

I can't understand why active state doesn't keeping if I refresh my page. I work with ng-route and everything it's ok , just active state work wrong. Can you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: Because after load you have `$scope.selected = 0` and  `$scope.isActive()` will be resolved as `0 === item`.

Comment: It depends what do you want to do.

Comment: when i refresh my page , I want  active state to be keeped . Now, when i refresh, active stare return to main page.

Answer (score 0):

On startup of your controller, you should fetch current route somehow and select a particular item basing on this route.

For example, you can add `slug` field to your routes:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/pets', {
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: /*...*/,
        slug: 'pets'
    }) /* ... */;
```

And then read it in your controller:

```
function yourController($scope, $routeParams) {
    /*...*/
    var selectedSlug = $routeParams.slug;
    if (selectedSlug) {
        $scope.selected =  /* find item by selected slug */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'slug' to routeParams

```
$routeProvider.
when('/pageUrl/:slug', {
    templateUrl: viewUrl,
    controller: someController
});
```

In Controller

```
.controller('someController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location) {
   if ($routeParams.slug) {
      $scope.selected = $routeParams.slug
   }

   $scope.select= function(slug) {
      $location.path('/pageUrl/' + slug);
   };

})
```

In view:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-controller="MenuItemCtrl as vm">
     <li ng-repeat="item in names" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" ng-click="select(item.slug)" ng-show="{{item.up===true}}" ng-class="{active: item.slug == selected}"> 
         <a href="javascript:void(0)">{{item.name}}</a>  
     </li>
</ul>
```